# Exporting data from ArcGIS Desktop to .txt?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, file-geodatabase

I have a file-geodatabase.  It is a road network of a city.

Now I want to export the data into a .txt file for map matching.

I have installed ArcGIS Desktop and not used that software before.

What should I do next?

open the data with ArcMap

[image: open the data with ArcMap]

txt format

[image: expect like this]

I am completely new to GIS field!

Answer (score 3):

You are always able to export the attribute table, but remember this is only the attribute table and does not include the geometry field.  For points, many times there are x,y columns with the coordinates, but for lines and polygons you probably want to decide which standard spatial format you are most comfortable with.

Steps for attribute table export are in the help on [Exporting tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000001t000000)

Answer (score 1):

This output looks similar to the [ungenerate command](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00130000001w000000) for coverage data.
But only available with coverage data and arcgis advanced.

I don't have advanced license so I use fme to generate something close to this.  There is not a tool I know of in arcgis to get exactly this type of output. Without some customization.